# How to make Entity Framework create database before using it outside DbContext?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, hangfire

In certain test environments, I have configured my application to create a new instance of it's database using Entity Framework migrations when the database does not already exist.

I am also using Hangfire, and have configured it use SQL Server in my OWIN startup class. At present I am instantiating a new instance of my DbContext to force database creation prior to configuring Hangfire to use the database:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            // Force database creation before configuring Hangfire to use it.
        }

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("myConnection");
        // ...
    }
}
```

This feels a bit hacky. What is the recommended way to ensure Entity Framework has created the database before it is used outside of the DbContext?

Comment: Are you talking about the hangfire database? That will get automatically created anyway

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but you can use a `DbMigrator` to create the database and apply the existing migrations: `var migrator = new DbMigrator(new DbMigrationsConfiguration());`
`migrator.Update();` Also if you use a database initializer of type `DbMigrateToLatestVersion` you get this behavior automatically.

Comment: You can explicitly invoke the database initializer like this: `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, 
    Migrations.Configuration>());`
    `dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);`

Comment: @tomredfern It doesn't seem like this is still true; Hangfire will create the tables, but it doesn't seem to automatically create the database.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson that's my experience too. Just added an answer based on Diana's comment (and our current practise) in case you were interested.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson - you're right of course, the tables get created

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the snippet in the question isn't necessarily enough by itself (depending upon platform and other EF configuration settings), so we actually make it explicit in the code now (as per Diana's comment), which also makes it feel less hacky:

```
// Trigger database creation before Hangfire tries to use it.
var initializer = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, MyConfiguration>(true);
Database.SetInitializer(initializer);
var connectionString = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(connectionString))
{
    dbContext.Database.Initialize(false);
}
```